# Img tag src matching PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to match src="URL" tags like the following:

```
src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ulEY6FtwbtU/Twye18FlT4I/AAAAAAAAAEE/CHuAAgfQU2Q/s320/DSC_0045.JPG"
```

Basically, anything that has somre sort of bp.blogspot URL inside of the src attribute. I have the following, but it's only partially working:

```
preg_match('/src=\"(.*)blogspot(.*)\"/', $content, $matches);
```

Comment: And what would "partially working" mean?

Comment: Some test data and example results would assist in troubleshooting this with you.

Comment: Not strong enough, but src="([^"]*bp\.blogspot\.com[^"]*)" should match normal cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one accepts all blogspot urls and allows escaped quotes:

```
src="((?:[^"]|(?:(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\\"))+\bblogspot\.com/(?:[^"]|(?:(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\\"))+)"
```

The URL gets captured to match group 1.

You will need to escape `\` and `/` with an additional `\` (for each occurence!) to use in `preg_match(…)`.

Explanation:

```
src=" # needle 1
( # start of capture group
    (?: # start of anonymous group
        [^"] # non-quote chars
        | # or:
        (?:(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\\") # escaped chars
    )+ # end of anonymous group
    \b # start of word (word boundary)
    blogspot\.com/ # needle 2
    (?: # start of anonymous group
        [^"] # non-quote chars
        | # or:
        (?:(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\\") # escaped chars
    )+ # end of anonymous group
    ) # end of capture group
" # needle 3
```

Comment: @Kolink: Sure. It accepts a prefix consisting of either `[^"]` or `"` preceded by an uneven (thus escaping) number of `\`. Then it searches for `blogspot.com` requiring the leading `b` to not be preceded by a letter (`\b`: word boundary) and then a suffix to which the same rules apply as for the prefix. The fancy stuff is required for accepting escaped quoted.

Comment: Yeah, and was the 2 b's in blogspot intentional? Also, what /'s and \'s need to be escaped? Because there are a ton of them ha

Comment: The `\b` is a regex meta char that denotes "word boundaries" (either end of a word). And you need to escape **all** of the `back-slashes` for being inside a string literal and the `forward-slash` for not being mistaken with the `/.../` regex bounding syntax. No need to do it manually, though. Find & replace will help you ;) It'd be a huge mess (and not readable/understandable) if I'd posted it in an already escaped form, so I chose to leave that to you. ;)

Comment: @Kolink: Just in case you didn't notice: I updated my answer and added a thorough explanation of the regex. Unfortunately StackOverflow's syntax highlighter doesn't seem to like commented regexes too much. So ignore the whitespace and read the stuff between every `#` and their next `line-break` as comments.