# Get html image tag from string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to get HTML image tag url from the given string. I am using the PHP method `preg_match("/src=\"([^\s\"]+)/",$body,$matches);` which works fine for most cases, however I am having trouble getting the url from the following link...

```
src=http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-LqmY1y4DCO0/T39EoCmzfoI/AAAAAAAACp0/TRKmdPmhJ90/s640/how+to+make+cheesecake+carrots,+orange+cheesecake+recipe,+recipes,+Easter+dessert+.jpg
```

Could anyone explain the reason for this failing please.

Comment: Is this really a Java question? `preg_match()` isn't a method that conforms to the default Java naming standards - ie `pregMatch();` would be more correct.

Comment: Sorry accidentally added Java.  Thanks for correcting.

Comment: Parsing HTML or HTML attributes with regular expressions is a bad idea. Are you sure you couldn't do this with DOM methods? (in PHP)

Comment: I found another post addressing the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122208/img-tag-src-matching-php-regex but I get an error.  I have no knowledge in PHP so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your test string does not have " character after src= and your regular expression expects it so it does not match.
If you want to test your regular expressions I recommend you use program RegexCoach, it highlights matches and allows you to step through matching processs so you can easily see where it fails.

Answer (score 0):

loading with DOM?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($var);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$img = $xpath->query('//img[@src]');

if(count($img)>0)
{
    foreach($img as $i)
        echo $i->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner at this.  Do you know how to integrate this within a module in Drupal?

Comment: sorry i put img tag but you don't use any specific tag, see the next answer

Answer (score 0):

try it with this regex :)

```
preg_match_all("/src=([^\\s]+)/", $body, $m);
print_r($a);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Though it still doesn't pull images from certain blogs.  I have tried on two blogs both on blogger platform.  One works and one doesn't.  I wonder if it's their blog setting that disallow images to be extracted?

Comment: aaaah i think is because some tags are betweeen quotes

Comment: the answer is 95% okay as per me, only the image name which has a space in between the name is not coming fully.